# Keyboard emoji not available in some apps

Tags: keyboard, emoticons

Google updated their keyboard app yesterday, a few welcome tweaks, but something seems to have broken for me.

In some apps that are badly built, I've no longer got access to emojis. If I long press the enter key, I *should* be presented with 3 (teal circle) options here above the enter key - instead I see only two. Emojis are missing.

They're in the bottom left key section I hear you cry! Nope, these are just plain text smileys, full image emojis are nowhere to be seen in this case.

[image]

Most other apps I've used do indeed appear to work properly and have the full functionality present.

It's worth noting that the emojis in the app I'm seeing this **did** work before the update.

Is there anyway to fix this, like forcing the same layout for any app?

And no, I don't want to download another keyboard, I really like the Google stock keyboard, this is it's only flaw right now.

Comment: Why don't you search for a previous version of the same keyboard?

Comment: I was hoping there would be some setting to override this behaviour. The new update apart from this, is quite nice.